# Matplotlib both axis values overlapping

Tags: python, matplotlib

Just started using Matplotlib, I have imported csv file using URL, In this file there are almost 190+ entries for countries along with specific regions in which this country belongs to like India in Asia. I am able to plot all data but due to these much data all X Axis and Y Axis values overlap each other and getting messy.

Code:

```
country_cols = ['Country', 'Region']
country_data = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cs109/2014_data/master/countries.csv",names=country_cols)

country_list = country_data.Country.tolist()
region_list = country_data.Region.tolist()

plt.plot(region_list,country_list)
```

And output shows like this

[image]

For sake of learning, I am using a simple line chart, I also want to know which graph type should be used for representing such data? It would be so much helpful.

Comment: I would use wordcloud https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/wordcloud-python and group countries by continent. With your current graph, you could flip the axes and increase the spacing between the axis and the country name label for every other entry (and rotate the label by 90°)

Comment: Hey, I am new to python, Can you provide code snippet Please? It would be so helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need fig.autofmt_xdate()

Try this code:

```
 country_cols = ['Country', 'Region']
 country_data = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cs109/2014_data/master/countries.csv",names=country_cols)

 country_list = country_data.Country.tolist()
 region_list = country_data.Region.tolist()
 fig = plt.figure()
 plt.plot(region_list,country_list)
 fig.autofmt_xdate()
 plt.show()
```

Comment: what is fig here?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I updated the code, try it again :)

Comment: Yes, this solves for the x-axis. What are the steps for Y-axis?

Comment: I have solved it using fig = plt.figure(figsize =(6,48)) but thing is the size become very large so Is there any better way other than this?